# How regression adjusts categorical variables?

Tags: regression, categorical-data, categorical-encoding

Could you explain in simple language, how adjusting works for categorical variables in regression? Googled without any success.

**Let's take a model:**

income ~ country + city + money_spent_on_education

**Handling of continuous variables:**

money_spent_on_education - sets this to mean value while assessing the effects of other predictors

**Handling of categorical variables:**

county - does regression just equalises the county levels in analysis (e.g. Germany and USA have both same weight on b coefficients)?

city - does regression just equalises the city levels in analysis (e.g. Berlin and New York have both same weight on b coefficients)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer depends on **contrasts**: how you code these factors and what is your baseline.

A lot of software operates from a perspective of experimental analysis and so takes the first factor level as the baseline and other factor levels just express a difference from that baseline.

There are all sorts of contrasts you can use, as explained at [UCLA's IDRE page on contrasts](https://stats.idre.ucla.edu/r/library/r-library-contrast-coding-systems-for-categorical-variables/).

Some contrasts will make the intercept represent the grand men and the baseline effect; some will make the intercept be the grand mean; some allow for ordering of factor levels; and, some allow for easily comparing adjacent factor levels.

Comment: (+1) nicely and efficiently stated, with a very useful link. Even the treatment coding that you first describe can differ among software packages; R uses the first level as the reference, while at least one commercial package (SPSS?) uses the last.